# How make a dspace docker work space?

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose, dspace

I have a little experience with docker-compose and Laravel, this set goes fine, but how could I make the same with dspace?
I would like to have work directory in my host, not all into container.

I have tried dspace-docker that is in dockerhub, is this one: https://github.com/4Science/dspace-docker, but I had troubles wit him.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following Docker images can be used to run DSpace locally.  There is not yet a published Docker Compose file.
- https://hub.docker.com/r/dspace/dspace-tomcat/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/dspace/dspace-postgres-pgcrypto/

The following page describes how to utilize these images on either Windows or MacOS: https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images/blob/master/tutorial.md

Here are the key steps.

- Clone DSpace
- Configure a local.cfg file that assumes DSpace will run in a container. [dspace-install] will be within the container.
- Run the DSpace maven build on your workstation
- Run the DSpace `ant update` in a container to install the code at [dspace-install]

The MacOS setup is described here.  See the link above for Windows.

```
docker network create dspacenet
docker volume create pgdataD6
docker run -it -d --network dspacenet -p 5432:5432 --name dspacedb -v pgdataD6:/pgdata -e PGDATA=/pgdata dspace/dspace-postgres-pgcrypto
docker run -it --rm --network dspacenet -v "$(pwd)"/dspace/target/dspace-installer:/installer -v dspaceD6:/dspace -w /installer dspace/dspace-tomcat ant update clean_backups
docker run -it --network dspacenet -v dspaceD6:/dspace -p 8080:8080 --name dspacetomcat -e DSPACE_INSTALL=/dspace dspace/dspace-tomcat
```

Comment: Thank you. Well, I have used this https://github.com/4Science/dspace-docker but does not working, I get a lot errors. I will try your proposal.

Comment: Pedrog, did that work for you?  I want to make sure that the instructions for those docker images are easy to follow.

Comment: Well, is a first step... so it have been helpful. Anyway I would like mount with docker-compose so I working in that. Thanks